# Structuring frontend and backend (AngularJS, Slim)

Tags: angularjs, frontend, backend, slim

**Questions**: What is the correct / proper structure of Frontend and Backend together? How do I publish whole project after It's done? Will it just work if I copy it all to some host? (I know I have to modify DB paths and stuff, I'm worried about all the updating that composer does.. or am I understanding it all wrong)?

**Short explanation** of how I got here: I'm a student developing a Time management web application (Projects, Tasks..). I have knowledge of PHP (Slim), JS (JQuery, Angular), HTML, CSS (Bootstrap), SQL. My development flow was first creating a database and setting up an Apache server (Linux). After that I started coding by simply creating a folder, adding sub-folders for backend (DB operations..) and frontend (js, css, view, images...) when I needed them. All the includes were downloaded when I needed them (jquery, bootstrap etc.). I never used composer/ npm /bower.. Which brings me to this:

**Current situation**: I was about to upgrade form Slim 2 to Slim 3. In the last 6 hours of googling I've completely lost motivation and at the moment I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing. Almost every article/tutorial I read gives me different information: Composer? Bower? npm? Yo?... I feel like I'm doing it all wrong. I tried few of those seeds that create a clean project for you.. **WHAT ARE ALL THOSE FILES**. I even tried one that creates clean structure of Angular and Slim in one project. Needlessly to say I'm completely lost. I feel like I did all those 100 hours of coding while I should be studying for nothing, since i have no idea how to properly use it.

I'd really appreciate any tip, suggestion, links to stuff that'll help. I feel like all the knowledge of coding I have is just useless since I have no idea how to use it properly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple to work with composer and npm for Slim3 and Angular2 
both are different files and main folders

For Slim you will use composer to download all files in **vendor** folder

For Angular you will use npm to install all files in **node_modules** 
folder

Even the required file is different **composer.json** for slim and **package.json** for Angular.

I use Slim with Angular 4 now inaa project and every thing is going smoothly

I don't know what kind of problems you faced, but I'm sure both can work together